# GCC variable with __attribute__ is treated like an initialized

Tags: c, gcc, attributes, ld

If I use the `__attribute__(section(".section_i"))`, the variable is treated as an initialized variable.
Let's take a quick look at the following example(declared as global variable):

```
 static unsigned char array[1024] __attribute__((section (".section_i")));
```

The above declaration will increase the data size by 1k even though I have not initialized the array.
How can I mark the **variable** as not initialized to avoid the increasing of data section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> static unsigned char array[1024] __attribute__((section (".section_i")));
> ```
>
> The above declaration will increase the data size by 1k even though I have not initialized the array. How can I mark the variable as not initialized to avoid the increasing of data section?

OK, this is not actually about "initialized" or "not initialized"; this is about whether or not the variable is treated as "common", not requiring preallocated space in the data *segment* of the executable image.  (Unlinked object files have sections; fully linked executables and shared libraries have segments.)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes *says* that this is controlled with the "common" attribute, so

```
static unsigned char array[1024] __attribute((section(".section_i"), common));
```

is documented to do what you want (provided that your linker script cooperates; the section named `.section_i` must be put into the appropriate segment; for historical reasons, the name of that segment is probably "BSS").  However, when I actually try that with the compiler I have to hand (which is indeed GCC 7.3, native compiler for x86_64-Linux) it generates assembly language that might not do the right thing.  You should try it with your compiler anyway; it is probable that this is just a plain old bug in the x86-64 back end, and one that may not be duplicated in the back end for whatever embedded environment you're working with.

Note that you should inspect a fully linked executable image before concluding that this does not work.  It's possible that the variable will take up space in the *object file* that defines it, but not in the executable.

For incredibly stupid reasons that I regret I even know about and do not want to attempt to explain, it may also help to call the section `.bss.section_i` instead of just `.section_i`.  This may also make it easier to write the linker script.

Comment: `For incredibly stupid reasons that I regret I even know about` made my day, as I totally share your point!